# How to use prop inside another prop as default value in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using [this](https://github.com/manjufy/v-minusplusinput) package from git hub for minus plus input for vuejs and in v2 folder example there is a sample file named plusminusfield.vue and this is what I used for using it :

```
 export default {
    props: {



        value: {
            default: 0,
            type: Number
        },
       base_capacity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        min: {
             default: here I want to use the sent variable which is defined above and that is base_capacity 
 if I send a hard code like 5 it works well but I want to make it dynamic
             type:Number
        },
        max: {
            default: 22,
            type: Number
        },
    },
    data(){
        return {

            newValue: this.base_capacity,
        }
    },
```

and here is the methods for minus plus the numbers of input and controlling the max and min values :

```
methods:{
        getNotificationClass (notification) {
            return `alert alert-${notification.type}`
        },
        mpminus: function () {
            if ((this.newValue) > this.min) {
                this.newValue = this.newValue - 1
                this.$emit('input', this.newValue)
            }

        },
        mpplus: function () {
            if (this.max === undefined || (this.newValue < this.max)) {
                this.newValue = this.newValue + 1
                this.$emit('input', this.newValue)
            }
        },

    },
 watch: {
        value: {
            handler: function (newVal, oldVal) {
                this.newValue = newVal
            }
        }
    },
```

so if I define it any where else and I use it in props I get the mutant error which the parent component change it and my app wont run and if I use the computed like below I comment the error in front of them :

```
computed: {
           min() {
             return this.min ? this.min : this.base_capacity //Maximum call stack size exceeded
         }
        min : this.base_capacity // the error is base_capacity not defined
    },
```

so is there any way that I pass the min for that input from the

Comment: You can do `this.newValue = this.base_capacity` in the `created` (or `mounted`) hook.

Comment: @Seblor not working with this error [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "min"

Comment: I don't believe it would be possible to set the default value of one prop to the value of another prop.

Comment: @Farshad This is an other error. This is because you are changing the `min` prop value somewhere else in your code. Maybe you set the model of an input to `min` which should not be the case

Comment: You could try using returning the using a function, but I'm just guessing here, e.g. : `default: () => { return this.base_capacity; }`

Comment: @DelenaMalan no still Cannot read property 'base_capacity' of undefined

Comment: @Seblor no i am not changing it any where look at edited question i added markup of html

Comment: there is no this at this moment, the component isn't initialized yet.

Comment: @RaduDiță i am a bit confused :|\

Comment: Here you can check: https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/bshL3ztk/ and confirm. then I will add to answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using it directly, use a factory function and return the value.

moreover, HTML attributes are case-sensitive.

Example: If you set the attribute as: `base-capacity`, Vue will automatically convert it into the camel-case as `baseCapacity` to access it from the script.

> Here is the official [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

```js
Vue.component('plus-minus', {
  template: '#vplusminus',
  props: {
    value: {
      default: 0,
      type: Number
    },
    baseCapacity: {
      default: 0,
      type: Number
    },
    min: {
      default: function () {
        return this.baseCapacity 
      },
      type: Number
    },
    max: {
      default: undefined,
      type: Number
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newValue: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getNotificationClass(notification) {
      return `alert alert-${notification.type}`
    },
    mpplus: function() {
      if (this.max === undefined || (this.newValue < this.max)) {
        this.newValue = this.newValue + 1
        this.$emit('input', this.newValue)
      }
    },
    mpminus: function() {
      console.log(this.min); // Here it is coming as 12
      if ((this.newValue) > this.min) {
        this.newValue = this.newValue - 1
        this.$emit('input', this.newValue)
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      handler: function(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.newValue = newVal
      }
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.newValue = this.value
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
.minusplusnumber {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}

.minusplusnumber div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.minusplusnumber #field_container input {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: none;
}

.minusplusnumber .mpbtn {
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.minusplusnumber .mpbtn:hover {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.minusplusnumber .mpbtn:active {
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <plus-minus :base-capacity="12" :value="16"></plus-minus>
  <plus-minus></plus-minus>
</div>

<script type="template/text" id="vplusminus">
  <div class="minusplusnumber">
    <div class="mpbtn minus" v-on:click="mpminus()">
      -
    </div>
    <div id="field_container">
      <input type="number" v-model="newValue" disabled />
    </div>
    <div class="mpbtn plus" v-on:click="mpplus()">
      +
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: https://github.com/manjufy/v-minusplusinput this is the component i use i didnt got what is your answer tbh bro

Comment: Updated the answer as far as I understood the question. you need to set the default value for a min to base_capacity so If you click on the minus, you will get min value as 12 i.e set under `base-capacity` from the component.

Comment: I've set the `:value` to `16` and now if you click on minus button, you can able to get till `12` as min is set to `12` now.

Comment: Cool. Good to hear!

Comment: Is this reactive?

Comment: Yes. It is reactive if you send it from the Parent component reactively.

Answer (score 23):

While the accepted answer will work for Vue 2.x, in Vue 3.x prop default factory functions no longer have access to `this`. Instead you can pass the component's props as an argument to the factory function:

```js
props: {
  ...
  baseCapacity: {
    default: 0,
    type: Number
  },
  min: {
    default: (props) => props.baseCapacity,
    type: Number
  },
  ...
},
```

See the migration guide: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/props-default-this.html

Comment: Mind that the order is important, in above example, if `min` were to come before `baseCapacity`, `props.baseCapacity` would be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use another `prop` as the default value. Even if they are available you have no guarantee regarding the order in which the props are evaluated.

A better approach is to use a computed property that takes into account both props and use that one inside your component.

```
computed: {
   minComputed () {
     return this.min ? this.min : this.base_capacity
   }
}
```

Also, remove the `default` value from the definition of `min`

Comment: take a look at this link its an input https://github.com/manjufy/v-minusplusinput it has options of minimum value and maximum now what i wana do it to set the min to a sent variable from laravel i just wanted to elaborate my self better :)

Comment: Got it, your problem stems from the fact that you are trying to set the default value for min to base_capacity. But your approach won't work. You need to define a min computed property and base that on the props value of min and base_capacity. You'll end up with the functionality you desire.

Comment: is that your answer ?? but when i tried that i got the error again leme try it again

Comment: I edited my answer, you also need to remove default from the definition of min.

Comment: i think its important to add this function to its for minus   mpminus: function () {
                if ((this.newValue) > this.min) {
                    this.newValue = this.newValue - 1
                    this.$emit('input', this.newValue)
                } so if u dont set the min it wont work and it wont minus any thing now its like this i dont get error but it wont work